# Multiply large number in parallel

Tags: c#

I wrote a multiply large number function and i want to change it to calculate the power of big numbers.

ex: (2321313200000888)^25 so i do like this:

```
public string power(string num1, int n)
{

    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    string answer= num1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        answer= multiply(num1, answer);

    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.richTextBox1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { richTextBox1.Text = answer; });
        this.label6.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { label6.Text = answer.Length.ToString(); });
        this.label2.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { label2.Text = timer.Elapsed.ToString(); });

    }


    return answer;
```

I want to do this in parallel to reduce the time how can i do that? I tried making task but it is the same as seqential.

Comment: What's wrong with [BigNum.pow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.pow(v=vs.110).aspx)? And what's the context? Are you computing a lot of these exponentiations? For what application?

Comment: You can't calculate a power by multiplying in parallel as each result is dependent on the previous result.  At best you could recursively calculate _pairs_ in parallel and continue until you have only one number left.

Comment: stringly arithmetic will always be slow...

Comment: it is realy big number for ex it is 1000 digit number so i can not use that.

Comment: If you had a list of numbers to multiply as a list called `sequence` then parallel linq has an aggregator, something like this: `(from x in sequence.AsParallel() select x).Aggregate((y1, y2) => y1 * y2);`

Comment: how can i use recursive calculation in parallel?

Comment: arash, is this for cryptography?

Comment: no actully it is one large number to a power of 2 digit number.

Comment: As already mentioned `BigInteger.Pow(BigInteger.Parse("2321313200000888"), 25).ToString()` will give you `1391052512241279878488446197231902011141665094364130111815003537197037603322766748781874624177484504851457018621971865199724461730485673588156795883833576622294066476460608245775516283323339586480216369729174048134461428015960564944986550850746506479936024181533232976415266102151571949631670796710093251832325188734240015034131308920279502825206013742932412949582162716082166529261568` :)

Comment: thank you
can i do pow function in parallel?

Comment: @arash Why parallel, just use `BigInteger` like @EZI showed you.

Comment: If you want my further help with your question, you need to add more details to your question.
1) Tell us about your application. Why do you need fast exponentiation? Why isn't the standard library sufficient?
2) Demonstrate that you've researched your question. What's your difficulty in understanding existing research on this issue? Google is your friend.

Comment: i need to be parallel because it calculate many times in a row.
So even a second is matter to me.
As you can see i put a timer and i want the fastest time.
i dont use standard libary becuse i can not parallize it and i think it cant calculate 1000 digit number to a power of 2 digit num

Comment: @arash Why do you need that parallelism? Have you measured the Biginterger results? Is it slow? Do you know its internal implementation? Maybe It utilizes some parallelism etc. Maybe cost of creating threads will be higher than do it in classical way. Many questions...

Comment: @arash Why do you think it can not calculate that? It can, and I'm pretty sure it can do it faster than any code you can come up with (parallel or not)

Comment: thanks a lot it work
and you are right it pretty fast

Answer (score 1):

I don't know an easy way to parallelize, but you can definitely reduce the number of multiplications.  The easiest way to consider the binary representation of the number (my apologies for lack of MathJax):

[image]

So first compute (by successive multiplication with itself):

[image]

Then multiply the three that are required.  This reduces from 24 multiplications to 7 multiplications.  The savings grows pretty quickly for very large powers, though the time varies quite a bit depending on how many bits are in the power.

You'll find that you can optimize the process if you're able to find a partition such that you have bigger exponents only once like in:

[image]

Comment: I just pulled out my lecture notes ready to write exactly what you wrote just now. :D @MathJax: When will they finally introduce that to SO? I mean .. c'mon ..

Comment: thanks it helps
so i gonna write a recursive power like you mention and i parallize it but i think because the answer always depend on the previous result it can't be parallize

Comment: Well you can calculate a "partition" such that you know the different exponents. Those different calculations would be parallelize able. Of course in the end you'd have to merge that stuff. But sometimes you'll get some good results. I'm going to add that to his answer.

Comment: Each partition is depend on previous one with this method.
i dont know how to seprate the calculation.

Comment: @arash, for the above example, you can, in principle, multiply (x^8 * x^1) in parallel with computing (x^8 * x^8).  This wouldn't be possible for all exponents (powers with two or fewer bits would always require serial computation), so it may not actually be worthwhile unless you expect large powers with a lot of bits.

Comment: yes at least i can breake the opration to 2 or 4 seprate calculaation

Comment: @DanBryant One point is missing. Suppose you want to calculate `a^b` where *a* or *b* can be greater than 32/64 bits.

Comment: @EZI, very large powers add some implementation complexity, but the principle is the same; a large number has an equivalent (large) base-2 representation.  In practice, though, if you have an exponent that exceeds 32-bits, you're likely going to start running into logistical issues with storage of the resulting number in a fixed point base.

Comment: @DanBryant I know principle is the same, but your answer doesn't show any way how to do it when a number is greater than 64 bits. how it can be represented, how can a multiplication can be done with a such number. ( there is no exponent or mantissa, they are all *big integers*)

Comment: @DanBryant BTW:  `if you have an exponent that exceeds 32-bits, you're likely going to start running into logistical issues with storage of the resulting number in a fixed point base` See my comment under the question.

Comment: @EZI, My answer was based on the OP already having a mechanism for representing large numbers and multiplying them.  What I'm referring to by exponent here is the value `b` in the expression `a^b`.

Comment: @DanBryant OK, Sorry to say, but a useless answer.